# クリスタルレポートの書式設定の仕方

Tags: vb.net

.NET 初心者です。
クリスタルレポートの IFieldObject を小数以下第2位で四捨五入して表示したいのですが、どこで設定するのかわかりません。
教えてください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

レポートデザイナでIFieldObjectを選択し、プロパティウィンドウで`RoundingType`プロパティを`crRoundToTenth`(十分の1)にします。
ついでに表示される小数点以下の桁数を変更する場合は`DecimalPlaces`プロパティで変更できます。

コードで変更する場合は以下のようにできます。

```vb
Private Sub CrystalReport1_InitReport(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CrystalReport1.InitReport
    Dim report As ReportClass = CType(sender, ReportClass)
    For Each sec As Section In report.ReportDefinition.Sections
        For Each ro As ReportObject In sec.ReportObjects
            If (ro.Kind = ReportObjectKind.FieldObject) Then
                Dim field As FieldObject = CType(ro, FieldObject)
                If (field.DataSource.ValueType = FieldValueType.NumberField) Then
                    field.FieldFormat.NumericFormat.DecimalPlaces = 1
                    field.FieldFormat.NumericFormat.RoundingFormat = RoundingFormat.RoundToTenth
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。動くようになりました。